# jQuery doesn't work on dynamically loaded html

Tags: jquery

I have a webpage that has div tags in it that loads menu bar/sub bar content dynamically through jQuery (I want the content external so I can load it on multiple pages). In the page, there is a jQuery function that alters the menu bar contents when the mouse is over a specific part of the menu bar (like the one on msn.com).

The problem is the content loads, but the jQuery doesn't work (using the `.on()` function). 
The first part of the function shows a sub menu based upon which menu item you mouse over. The second part(s) of the function set the background color of the mouse over-ed menu item and also sets the color of the other items back to its original.

If I put the content directly on the page, it works fine. Any help is appreciated as I can not figure this out.

**HTML - content loaded dynamically into each div**

```
<tr>
    <td align="center" valign="middle"> 
       <div id="menubar_index">
           <!--menubar contents are loaded dynamically-->
       </div>

    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td align="center" valign="middle"> 
       <div id="menubar_sub">
           <!--menubar contents are loaded dynamically-->
       </div>

    </td>
</tr>
```

**HTML Content that is loaded into first div(menubar_index):**

```
<div class="topgradientblueline">

    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="menuspacer">
            &nbsp;
        </div>
        <div id="dmsmenu" style="font-family:Sans-Serif; font-size:small; ">
            Document Management Solutions
        </div>
        <div id="lsTMFmenu" style="font-family:Sans-Serif; font-size:small; ">
            Life Science TMF Solutions
        </div>
        <div id="lssampmenu" style="font-family:Sans-Serif; font-size:small; ">
            Life Science Sampling Solutions
        </div>
        <div id="drsmenu" style="font-family:Sans-Serif; font-size:small; ">
            About DRS
        </div>
    </div>                

</div>
```

**HTML Content that is loaded into the second div(menubar_sub):**

```
<div style="height:50px; width:950px;">
    <div id="dmssubmenu" style="display: none">
        <a href="#" style="text-decoration:none">DMS Sub Menu</a>
    </div>
    <div id="lsTMFsubmenu" style="display: none">
        <a href="#" style="text-decoration:none">LSTMF Sub Menu</a>
    </div>
    <div id="lssampsubmenu" style="display: none">
        <a href="#" style="text-decoration:none">LSSamp Sub Menu</a>
    </div>
    <div id="drssubmenu" style="display: none">
        <a href="#" style="text-decoration:none">DRS Sub Menu</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

**jQuery that resides on the page:**

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#menubar_index").load("menubar_index.html");
    $("#menubar_sub").load("menubar_sub.html");
    $("#menubar_ims").load("menubar_ims.html");
    $("#pageheader").load("page_header.html");
    $("#footer_news").load("footer_news.html");
    $("#vmenubar_ims").load("vmenubar_ims.html");
    $("#vmenubar_tmfps").load("vmenubar_tmfps.html");
    $("#pagefooter").load("page_footer.html");
    });

      //jquery to show & hide divs
        $(document).ready(function() {


//          doc mgmt slns menu item
            $("#dmsmenu").on("mouseenter", function() {

//                hide/show sub menus
                  $("#dmssubmenu").show();
                  $("#lsTMFsubmenu").hide();
                  $("#lssampsubmenu").hide();                  
                  $("#drssubmenu").hide();

//                set background(white), text(orange) and cursor(pointer) of this item
                  $(this).css('background', '#ffffff')
                  $(this).css('color', '#DF7401');
                  $(this).css('cursor', 'pointer');

//                set background(blue), text(white) of all other menu items
                  $("#lsTMFmenu").css('background', '#0A0A2A');
                  $("#lsTMFmenu").css('color', '#ffffff');
                  $("#lssampmenu").css('background', '#0A0A2A');
                  $("#lssampmenu").css('color', '#ffffff');
                  $("#drsmenu").css('background', '#0A0A2A');
                  $("#drsmenu").css('color', '#ffffff');

            });

//          life sci TMF slns menu item            
            $("#lsTMFmenu").on("mouseenter", function() {

//                hide/show sub menus
                  $("#lsTMFsubmenu").show();
                  $("#dmssubmenu").hide();
                  $("#lssampsubmenu").hide();             
                  $("#drssubmenu").hide();

//                set background(white), text(orange) and cursor(pointer) of this item                  
                  $(this).css('background', '#ffffff');                  
                  $(this).css('color', '#DF7401');
                  $(this).css('cursor', 'pointer');

//                set background(blue), text(white) of all other menu items                  
                  $("#dmsmenu").css('background', '#0A0A2A');
                  $("#dmsmenu").css('color', '#ffffff');
                  $("#lssampmenu").css('background', '#0A0A2A');
                  $("#lssampmenu").css('color', '#ffffff');
                  $("#drsmenu").css('background', '#0A0A2A');
                  $("#drsmenu").css('color', '#ffffff');

            });

//          life sci samp slns menu item      
            $("#lssampmenu").on("mouseenter", function() {

//                hide/show sub menus                  
                  $("#lssampsubmenu").show();                  
                  $("#dmssubmenu").hide();
                  $("#lsTMFsubmenu").hide();
                  $("#drssubmenu").hide();

//                set background(white), text(orange) and cursor(pointer) of this item                               
                  $(this).css('background', '#ffffff')
                  $(this).css('color', '#DF7401');
                  $(this).css('cursor', 'pointer');

//                set background/text of other menu items back to normal
                  $("#lsTMFmenu").css('background', '#0A0A2A');
                  $("#lsTMFmenu").css('color', '#ffffff');
                  $("#dmsmenu").css('background', '#0A0A2A');
                  $("#dmsmenu").css('color', '#ffffff');
                  $("#drsmenu").css('background', '#0A0A2A');
                  $("#drsmenu").css('color', '#ffffff');

            });

//          about DRS menu item      
            $("#drsmenu").on("mouseenter", function() {

//                hide/show sub menus                  
                  $("#drssubmenu").show();                  
                  $("#dmssubmenu").hide();
                  $("#lsTMFsubmenu").hide();
                  $("#lssampsubmenu").hide();

//                set background(white), text(orange) and cursor(pointer) of this item                               
                  $(this).css('background', '#ffffff')
                  $(this).css('color', '#DF7401');
                  $(this).css('cursor', 'pointer');

//                set background/text of other menu items back to normal
                  $("#lsTMFmenu").css('background', '#0A0A2A');
                  $("#lsTMFmenu").css('color', '#ffffff');
                  $("#dmsmenu").css('background', '#0A0A2A');
                  $("#dmsmenu").css('color', '#ffffff');
                  $("#lssampmenu").css('background', '#0A0A2A');
                  $("#lssampmenu").css('color', '#ffffff');

            });


        });
    </script>
```

**CSS:**

```
#wrapper {
     width: 1360px;
     margin: 0 auto;
      background-color:#0B0B3B;
}

#dmsmenu, #lsTMFmenu, #menuspacer, #lssampmenu, #drsmenu {

    float: left;
    min-height: 20px;
    color:White;
    border-spacing:2px;

}
#dmsmenu {
     width: 230px;
     text-align:center;
     font-weight:bold;

}

#lssampmenu {
     width: 230px;
     text-align:center;
     font-weight:bold;

}

#drsmenu {
     width: 130px;
     text-align:center;
     font-weight:bold;

}
#menuspacer {
     width: 50px;

}

#lsTMFmenu {
     width: 220px;
     text-align:center;
     font-weight:bold;

}

.topgradientblueline 
{
    background-color: #0A0A2A;
    width:1100px;
    height:20px;        
}
```

Comment: use $(document).on("mouseenter","#lsTMFmenu", function() {

Comment: Show some effort, this kind of question is asked hundred times a month...

Comment: I changed the $(document).ready to .on and it worked like a charm Anoop. Thanks for the quick response.

Comment: Another problem now exists. When I click on one of the menu items, it takes me to a subpage, where I again, load the same menu/sub menu dynamically. I put     $("#dmssubmenu").show(); directly on the page so that the sub menu should automatically display on page load, but nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

To handle any delegated events you need to call the `.on()` over the `document` element , instead of the adding to the target selector, which may appear in the document dynamically.

so change this

`$("#lsTMFmenu").on("mouseenter", function() {`

to

`$(document).on("mouseenter","#lsTMFmenu", function() {`

this way your saying that whatever gets added to the `document` element  with respective selector `"#lsTMFmenu"`, attach the `mouseenter` event  callback .

You need to change this for other instances as well on your page.

**REF:http://api.jquery.com/on/**

Happy Coding :)